# Would the full unedited film of a movie made in 1930 still exist somewhere?

Tags: production, black-and-white

Suppose that a movie was made in 1930. Would the unedited film of that movie still exist somewhere and can be retrieved?

Comment: Possibly, but the odds are against it - see https://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/it/the-lost-picture-show-hollywood-archivists-cant-outpace-obsolescence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Thanks to Tetsujin for the [link](https://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/it/the-lost-picture-show-hollywood-archivists-cant-outpace-obsolescence)</sup>

### Almost certainly not.

The vast majority of pre-1930 film stock has been lost either due to destruction or simply that the nitrate film stock used at the time is was not suitable for long term storage.

> To understand how the movie studios and archives got into this predicament, it helps to know a little about what came before LTO. **Up until the early 1950s, filmmakers shot on nitrate film stock, which turned out to be not just unstable but highly flammable**. Over the years, entire studio collections went up in flames, sometimes accidentally and sometimes on purpose, to avoid the costs of storage. According to the Film Foundation, a nonprofit founded by director Martin Scorsese to restore and preserve important films, about half of the U.S. films made before 1950 have been lost, **including an astounding 90 percent of those made before 1929.**

Even if the complete film could be found and was *capable* of being restored, an extremely unlikely event in the first place, there has to be a **commercial or cultural reason** to do so.

Restoration is time consuming and expensive and there has to be a significant reason to attempt it.